# Infinity, ActiveRecord and MySQL: storage and comparison

Tags: mysql, ruby, activerecord, infinity

I have user input strings specifying the cost of an event (eg: "$4 for non-members"). I am trying to parse out the upper (and lower) bound of the cost (in the example, `upper == lower == 4.00`).

Suppose that a given string cannot be parsed (maybe it's blank). In this case, I want to be able to store in the database that the maximum cost of the event is infinity (and minimum 0). How do I do this using Mysql and ActiveRecord?

What I've tried:

```
> e = Event.find(1234)
> e.cost_max = 1.0/0.0
> e.save
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql::Error: Unknown column 'Infinity' in 'field list': UPDATE `events` SET `cost_max` = Infinity WHERE `id` = 1234
```

I've also tried marking cost_max with NULL, instead. This works in principle. However, I am using Ultrasphinx filters to retrieve events whose cost range has a non-empty intersection with a searched range. As Ultrasphinx filters accept only hash conditions (am I wrong?), my options are limited to this:

```
search_params[:filter].merge!(:cost_max => 0.0..99)
```

Meaning, no "OR cost_max is NULL" allowed.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the field type is a `double` it seems that you can store infinity values.

```
VALUE('1e500');
```

Then it's just a matter of using that as the upper bounds for the comparison.

For more information see [this thread](http://lists.mysql.com/java/5988) in the mysql mailing lists.

Comment: it's not a double, though I suppose I could make it double. Currently it's a float.
It seems, though, that mysql doesn't support infinity for its float:
http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?39,220571,220573#msg-220573